# Do docker pull using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-docker

I would like to do next steps using jenkins:

```
1- docker pull <image_name>
2- docker run -i -t <command>
```

I´ve installed docker plugin on jenkins but is it this prossible? The documentations in  [docker plugin page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Docker+Plugin) is very poor .

Comment: Docker appears in the 'Cloud' section of the Jenkins configuration, select "Docker" from the "Add a new cloud" drop down menu.
Click the Add button to add a new image. Next on Build of a job step you can use it.

Answer (score 1):

These steps are executed programmatically by the plugin.
Alternatively you can execute an script into a jenkins slave with docker installed in build->execute shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
export image=`docker images httpd|wc -l`
echo image $image
if [ "$image" -lt "1" ];
then
    docker pull httpd 
fi
export container=`docker ps -all -f="name=webcontainer"|wc -l`
echo container $container
if [ "$container" -gt "1" ];
then
    echo "Deleting webcontainer"
    docker rm -f webcontainer 
fi
BUILD_ID=dontKillMe docker run -d -t -p8888:80 --name webcontainer httpd
```

You can interact with created docker with below command:

```
`docker exec -it  webcontainer /bin/bash`
```

Answer (score 1):

These days (mid 2017, more than a year after the OP's question), you would use an inside directive of a [Jenkins pipeline](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/) to pull and run within a docker image some commands.

For instance ([Using Jenkins Pipelines with Docker](http://www.stuartellis.name/articles/jenkins-pipeline/)), using the [Docker Pipeline plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Docker+Pipeline+Plugin):

```
docker.image('ruby:2.3.1').inside {

    stage("Install Bundler") {
      sh "gem install bundler --no-rdoc --no-ri"
    }

    stage("Use Bundler to install dependencies") {
      sh "bundle install"
    }
}
```